# How does innerHTML actually work when set to resultant (result of array.filter) array?

Tags: javascript

In the following fiddle, [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8L0qtf29/2/), filter returns all those element that pass the test `(age >= 18)`. I have couple of doubts in this regards:

1. Why does `array.filter` return array elements even though I've explicitly defined a return value the callback return, here, an object's property `user.name`
2. How does `innerHTML` actually works in this case, since the `result_arr` is actually an array object (`typeof result_arr`) and AFAIK, values needs to be first extracted from `result_arr` and then written as the target elements content. It looks like, `JavaScript implicitly` does this for us?

**JS**

```
    function myFunction() {
       var result_arr = ages.filter(checkAdult);
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result_arr
    }


    var user = {
      name: 'Nick',
      age: 50
      }

    var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

    function checkAdult(age) {
        if(age >= 18){
                return user.name
         }
    }

    function myFunction() {
       var result_arr = ages.filter(checkAdult);
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result_arr
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `Array.filter` returns an array, always. `innerHTML` stringifies whatever you pass to it, always, and with arrays it just joins it together in the default way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does `array.filter` return array elements even though I've explicitly defined a return value the callback return, here, an object's property `user.name`

Because that's how [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works. All it cares about is whether the return value of the callback is *falsy*¹ or *truthy*. If you want to use a different value in the result array, you want [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It's common to see `.filter(...).map(...)` (common enough I've been known to create a `.filterMap` utility function).

> How does `innerHTML` actually works in this case, since the `result_arr` is actually an array object

`result_arr` is coerced to string, as with `String(result_arr)`. With arrays, coercing to string is the same as [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), which is the same as `.join(",")`.

---

¹ "falsy" and "truthy": A value that coerces to `false` when used in a condition (e.g., as a boolean) is a *falsy* value. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`. All other values are *truthy*.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does array.filter return array elements even though I've explicitly defined a return value the callback return, here, an object's property user.name

Because filter expects a boolean return type. If it's true, the element stays, if it's false, it doesn't.

[See mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): *The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.*

> How does innerHTML actually works in this case, since the result_arr is actually an array object (typeof result_arr) and AFAIK, values needs to be first extracted from result_arr and then written as the target elements content. It looks like, JavaScript implicitly does this for us?

[`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) will be implicitly called for you, creating a comma separated string. This behavior is [defined here in the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8)

Comment: Right @Teemu, I've been downvoted quite some times for stating toString() is called, but I've been investigating it further the same time and the spec says it's toString() - more exactly its `toPrimitive` that get's "called", that results in a call to toString for an array

Comment: Here's more https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1 @Teemu

Comment: `toString` is definitely what is used here, and stringifying an object in general. Voting at SO is nowadays weird. Blatantly wrong answers get upvotes, also totally dumb and/or off-topic questions get upvotes, and when you say something which is not obvious (but correct), you'll get down votes, unless you don't add a list of links to the specs too = ).

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit strange. Especially for someone who's self learning and a bit dependent on others input, the voting behavior here is confusing... @Teemu I don't care too much about the points, but it's a good indicator to how I did understand what I've been learning...+

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, if you want to filter *and* transform an array in one go (without iterating over the array twice), you can use `reduce`:

```js
var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];
var result_arr = ages.reduce((a, item) => {
  if (item >= 18) a.push(item  + 0.5);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(result_arr);
```